# Gradle build errors with firebase ui auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am taking a Udacity tutorial on Firebase and when I add the firebase ui auth dependency `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2` the build fails with errors. Please refer to the images and assist. Thanks.

The dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'],dir: 'libs')
testcompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
//Displaying images 
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
}
apply plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error
[image]

Comment: Please don't show images of code and errors.  It's far better to copy the text into a code block in the question, so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: @vivekverma yes they do, but since I did not create then and they are related to firebase ui, I imagine there may be a dependency conflict or something that is preventing it

Comment: This is difficult to understand. Please copy and paste dependencies and logcat. It seems like your styles/resource file is the trouble-maker.

Comment: @DougStevenson the question has an accepted answer and there are many ways to kill a cat ;).

Comment: The primary reason for using text is that your question becomes searchable for people who are having the exact same problem.  As a courtesy to everyone who use Stack Overflow, please consider using text instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
```

to this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```